# 14.04 won't save WPA password

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, password

Recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop 64 bit. Most things works great except it won't save my password for my wireless network, which is

```
Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
Authentication: Protected EAP (PEAP)
Inner authentication: MSCHAPv2
```

My user name and password are saved in the network manager, but every time I boot into Ubuntu, it asks for my wireless password and a certificate. I've told it to save my password and ignore the certificate n+ times, but no success.

Comment: You may wanna check out this, sounds like a fair solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/457739/111026 That worked for me, at least.
Good luck