# How to fix repeated "Authentication required by Wi-Fi network" [Broadcom BCM4323]?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

END RESULT******Netgear WNDA 3100 wifi stick will only connect to a network with no password.******

I am finding solutions all over the web, I have been searching for hours. However the people that are asking understand Ubuntu, so the steps how to get to and apply the solutions are never discussed. I convinced a friend to convert to Ubuntu from Winblows and I can't get the USB wifi stick to work. 
I found a solution that sounds like it would fix the problem, I just need help with "Linux for dummies" help:

"I have the same issue here (UQAM), it should have a certificate but, it does not. When you connect for the first time, it wont set it properly so, you need to go to /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections and find your connection name, edit the file. You should see this line:

```
system-ca-certs=true
```

change it to

```
system-ca-certs=false"
```

This is the website I found that from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Editing_Network_Settings_in_nm-connection-editor

Now I know this shows as a solution for a certificate issue, however I've seen other people use that solution to fix the password glitch.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]

$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
          RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

roy@roy-Inspiron-620:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: For clarification it is Ubuntu 14.04, and this is a well known issue. I simply do not understand how to get to and modify the Network Manager. I know it is a matter of command lines, I simply do not know which ones.

Comment: For 'I convinced a friend to convert to Ubuntu from Winblows and I can't get the USB wifi stick to wOrk.'  you should ask a different question. Have you found any related bug reports? Note you can [edit] information into your question

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, I am new to the forum and getting under the hood of linux. I have used Ubuntu years ago, and currently I am focusing on Raspbmc. I understand how the command line works, however SSHing XBMC (which is no longer necessary) and using command line to fix this issue that did not exist years ago is a bit more difficult.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: It looks like this chip is not supported by any linux drivers. The only option is to install a Windows driver througt ndiswrapper.

Comment: Would you mind walking me through that? This is the last hurdle to complete the OS install, it sucks to be at the finish line yet still in over my head.

Comment: I made an answer. Please also add output of `usb-devices`

Comment: roy@roy-Inspiron-620:~$ modinfo | grep 9011
modinfo: ERROR: missing module or filename.

Comment: That was incorrect. I want to find out which driver is currently used. You do not need to post all `usb-devices`, but the section where your device with `Vendor=0846` `ProdID=9011`

Comment: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, Inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]

Comment: No. Run `usb-devices` in terminal and post a section about your device. Post it it your question by [edit]. Not here.

Comment: T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0846 ProdID=9011 Rev=00.01
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom
S:  Product=BCMUSB 802.11 Wireless Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=25986
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=200mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=02 Prot=ff Driver=ndiswrapper

Comment: It looks like ndiswrapper driver is installed already. Did you install that?

Comment: Yes I did, it is one of the things I tried but was not sure if I did it right because it did not solve the problem. I'm nearing burnt out and just want this finished.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add there `iwconfig` output. PLEASE DO NOT POST IT IN COMMENTS.

Comment: Do not do `cd bcm4323x_5.10.79.30_XP` do last 3 commands.

Comment: After that try to connect to your router.

Comment: I made a typo. `sudo ndiswrapper -m`

Comment: I corrected command. Does it work?

Comment: The commands entered successfully, however the problem remains.

Comment: What does it mean? Do you see access points in Network Manager? And post output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: To clarify the wifi dongle is "seeing" the router, the problem is when I enter the correct password it keeps popping up “Authentication required by Wi-Fi network” and will not connect. I apologize if I was not clear enough, this problem has been around awhile (since 2013) and I assumed it was well known just not yet addressed by the programmers.

Comment: OK. What is the SSID (name) of your network?

Comment: It is "mycci63"

Comment: Try this. http://askubuntu.com/a/457739/167850

Comment: Press "Choose Certificate" and add that like in that answer. Then uncheck "All users may connect to this network" in Network Manager.

Comment: I tried going to "General" tab and unticking "All users may connect to this network", that did not work.

Comment: Did you add the certificate?

Comment: I don't have the "CA certificate" issue, only the password not being accepted. Also, I'm using Chromium if that makes any difference--I mean that was showing mozilla...

Comment: Can you disable security in your router for a while? Does it connect?

Comment: I disabled the password on my router, and it connected.

Comment: You can set WEP encryption. It is better than nothing.

Comment: I just ordered a Kootek wifi dongle from Amazon, it's compatible with Linux. In the meantime I'm tethered to the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no compatible linux driver for this adapter. A Windows driver can be installed this way.

Do this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 ndiswrapper-dkms
wget http://wikidevi.com/files/Drivers/Broadcom/bcm4323x_5.10.79.30_XP.zip
unzip bcm4323x_5.10.79.30_XP.zip -d bcm4323
cd bcm4323
sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmwlhigh5.inf
sudo ndiswrapper -m
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

But it seems that there is no way to connect to WPA secure networks.

The only solution is to replace this dongle with something else, if security is vital. WEP may work, but it is not very much secure.