# Not able to connect to school wifi network in Ubuntu 16.04 - need to edit ca-certificate

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, certificates

My school asks us to do this to connect to the wifi in the ca-certificate

Search for the line:

```
system-ca-certs=true
```

Change this line to:

```
system-ca-certs=false
```

The problem is that I cannot find this line in the ca-certificate.

I can't connect to the network. A dialogue box pops up every time asking for my user id and password for the school wifi, I enter the right credentials but it doesn't work.

P.S  There is no problem in connecting to my home wifi network.

these are [the instructions given by my school][1] for connecting to the wifi

> The settings are:
>
> - Security Type: WPA2 Enterprise
> - Username: ldap-Username
> - Password: ldap-Password
> - Authentication: PEAP
> - PEAP version: automatic
> - Inner  authentication: MSCHAPV2
> - ca-certificate: none
>
> Note: For Ubuntu 14.04 users-
>
> The ca-certificate settings has to be changed to false. This may be
>   done in the following way:
>
> Open the file in an editor of your choice:
>   `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IITB-Wireless`
>
> Search for the line:
>
> ```
> system-ca-certs=true
> ```
>
> Change this line to:
>
> ```
> system-ca-certs=false
> ```

THIS IS THE CA_CERTIFICATE

[connection]

id=IITB-Wireless

uuid=xxxxxxxxx

type=wifi

permissions=

secondaries=

[wifi]

mac-address=D8:5D:E2:BC:D2:05

mac-address-blacklist=

mac-address-randomization=0

mode=infrastructure

seen-bssids=

ssid=IITB-Wireless

[wifi-security]

group=

key-mgmt=wpa-eap

pairwise=

proto=

[802-1x]

altsubject-matches=

ca-cert=/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt

eap=ttls;

identity=xxxxxxx

password=xxxxxxx

phase2-altsubject-matches=

phase2-autheap=mschapv2

[ipv4]

dns-search=

method=auto

[ipv6]

addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy

dns-search=

ip6-privacy=0

method=auto

Comment: Possibly the same problem as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/456970/constantly-asked-for-wifi-password-and-ca-certificate

Comment: no,not that one

Comment: Question is clearer now, but probably a dupe of this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/279762/how-to-connect-to-wpa2-peap-mschapv2-enterprise-wifi-networks-that-dont-use-a-c

Comment: What are the exact instructions by your school?

Comment: i will edit that above(do see)

Comment: the problem is i cannot the find that line in the ca-certificate,so how can i change it!!

Comment: For starters theres a typo in the path change "/etc/NetworkManagers" to "/etc/NetworkManager"

Comment: my bad,i made a mistake in typing.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu

Comment: What does `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IITB-Wireless` contain?

Comment: it is the path to the ca-certificate.

Comment: i have posted the ca-certificate up there(do see)

Comment: any solutions guys?

Answer (score 0):

edit the file:

```
gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

add these at the end of the file:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

restart the network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```